# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o13468.csv when trying to write csv file in docker volume

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed the all-spark-notebook docker image, but when I try to write csv file in the docker volume, this error occurs:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o13468.csv.
```

How to fix it please?

Comment: Could you please include the dockerfile and the code you are trying to run in the question.

Comment: @viggnah I use this container: jupyter/all-spark-notebook. I didn't modify the docker file I just use it in my project.  I added a docker volume and I want to save a csv file in this volume using : dataset.write.options(header='true').csv("location/data.csv"

Comment: You need to give more details to try to debug the issue. Are you running this image - https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/all-spark-notebook and following the docker run commands here - https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. Also, please post the code you are trying to run to write the csv, that might help!

Comment: yes I use this container. I fixed the issue by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780824/py4jjavaerror-an-error-occured-while-calling-o8660-save-when-trying-to-save-csv) however another error occus : `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'spark-volume/data.csv`.... but when i used the terminal i can write in this volume. so I have permission. so why this error appears?